# Getting error cmd or running another program that don,t connected with the file

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    printf("hello world");

    return 0;
}
```

My code is like that but everytime i run it always get another code that like this

blinking strip that use to be scanf and the output is -1 if i enter random answer or another answer
it is don,t reconnected with the code

Anyone can help me why everytime i run the program always like that?

Comment: How are you running the program and what ```#include```s do you have? E.G. to use printf i guess you included ```stdio.h``` right?

Comment: yes i included the `stdio.h` so the program can run but it still the same program that run @JohnSmith

Comment: how are you running your program? command line? IDE? something else?

Comment: i,m running it with devc++ compiler and the devc++ after compile and it run in cmd after that it give me the option of to insert a string or something as the answer -1 every time u type a char or if a number it will give a random number value? 
After that it will close and don't even run `printf("Hello world")` it's so confusing why my program like that? @JohnSmith

Comment: I never used devc++ but i'm guessing you are compiling and executing the wrong code. See if there is an option to choose the project or something like that and  check that it's the right one

Comment: it,s the right code i,m compiling and it also says i,m compiling that file not another but the exe is tell me to type a string and the result is -1 @JohnSmith

Comment: i,m done with this sorry @JohnSmith. so i found the problem is i forgot to save the name of file with _ so i just give it a space not _ so the file wont run or running the same file that have _
And also thank you for helping